# How to implement and communicate via websockets in an iOS-app?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, websocket

I want to create a simple app which contains a UIWebview. 
Now I want to communicate via websockets with that page. 
For example when I click on a button on that page, 
I want to get some strings from that server, so I can work with that information within my app.

Is that possible? Or are there other ways to do that?
Thanks for every comment..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be worth checking out [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (note: I am a co-founder), as we have an iOS library which will save you a lot of hassle: https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher

Comment: @dctanner can u help me in implementing that.I need to include this for the chating purpose in my project.I was searching for a tutorail for implementing this?

Answer (score 6):

I just released [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket), a native WebSocket library that conforms to the latest standard.

The author of the iOS libPusher library has a branch that uses SocketRocket too.